# Netbeans not executing JavaFX application properly

Tags: java, button, layout, netbeans, javafx

I am starting up with javaFX application on Netbeans and trying sample codes. Problem I am facing is that when I run the code from Netbeans the application runs successfully but buttons are not arranged properly. But when I run it from the jar file from binary folder it works fine. is there any fix for that in Netbeans ?

here is the code I am using:

```
package guiexperiments;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUIExperiments extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btOK = new Button("OK");
    Scene scene = new Scene(btOK, 300, 350); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("MyJavaFX"); // Set the stage title 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage 
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage


    Stage stage = new Stage(); // Create a new stage 
    stage.setTitle("Second Stage"); // Set the stage title
    // Set a scene with a button in the stage
    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Button("New Stage"), 300, 300)); stage.show();
    stage.setResizable(false);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

}
```

Sorry can't post images as I need 10 reputation points to post images ... urgh.

Comment: What version net beans you are using ? Java version?

Comment: Add the link of image you're trying to upload, someone among us would do it for you...

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not using any layouts

Try this code and you will understand

package Example;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Click Me");

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
 }
```